# AspNet Core : how to get current controller object in a service

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

I built a .NetCore 2.1 project and have a base controller class like this

```
public class MyBaseController:Controller
{
    #region Properties

    protected readonly ILogger Logger;
    protected readonly VVDCCore.Tools.Interfaces.IResourceManager Resx; 

    protected IDictionary<string,string> ExtraParameters;

    #endregion

    #region CONSTRUCTOR

    public BaseController(ILogger<BaseController> logger,
        VVDCCore.Tools.Interfaces.IResourceManager resxManager)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        Resx = resxManager;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

All my controllers are child of this base class.

I have a service (ResourceServices which implements IResourceManager interface) which permits to retrieve a value depending of a key and the context.

I know how to access controller's name and action's name in the service thanks to IActionContextAccessor interface.
But I would like to obtain current controller object.
In the service, I need to access the property ExtraParameters from my baseController but don't know how to do that

To sum up I would like to do something like this

```
public class ResourcesServices{

    public ResourceServices([CurrentController] controller)
    {
        var extraParameters = ((MyBaseController)controller).ExtraParameters;
    }
}
```

Any way to this?
TIA

Comment: You can do a simple typecast. But it is a suspect design, a Service should not need to know about (depend on) its caller. Because that is a circular dependency. Can't you pass the relevant data as parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reference controller object to others classes.
Instead provide only information class requires.

```
public class ResourcesServices
{
    public ResourceServices(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var extraParameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

If you are using Dependency Injection and if `ExtraParameters` are known only during runtime (`ResourcesServices` instance can not be instantiated).
Then consider to pass parameters to the method of `ResourcesServices` which will use them.

```
public class ResourcesServices
{        
    public ResourceServices() { }

    public void DoSomething(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        var extraParameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

When `ResourceServices` class requires "ExtraParameters" to be provided in constructor, you can create factory class which will be responsible for creating proper instance of `ResourceServices` with runtime values.

```
public class ResourcesServicesFactory
{        
    public ResourcesServicesFactory() { }

    public ResourcesServices Create(IDictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        return new ResourcesServices(parameters);
    }
}   

public class ChildController : MyBaseController
{
    private readonly ResourceServiceFactory _factory;


    public ChildController(  
        ILogger<BaseController> logger,
        VVDCCore.Tools.Interfaces.IResourceManager resxManager,
        ResourceServiceFactory factory) : base(logger, resxManager)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var service = _factory.Create(ExtraParameters);
        service.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Consider controller as an Entry point of your application, which main responsibility pass "input" to the service and return output to the client.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
the factory seems to be the best/cleanest solution for me
thanks a lot